# Counting 'char' and converting line to <h1> tag <h2> tag etc HASKELL

Tags: html, haskell, replace, count

Okay, after a night of work, I've ended up with these sections of code that has been giving me problems.
First, I want to apologize for, which alot of you will think are dumb mistakes..

first section is the convertToHTML -

```
  convertToHTML :: String -> String
  convertToHTML [] = [] --prevents calling head on empty line
  convertToHTML x --here is where I know I'm missing something.
           | x                  == "---"    = "<hr/>" --this works!
           | doubleHashes x     == "True"   = "<h2>" ++ x ++ "</h2>" --also wrong
           | doubleHashes x     == "False"  = "<h1>" ++ x ++ "</h1>" --also wrong
           | otherwise          = x
```

the convertToHTML' code however works nicely...

```
 convertToHTML' :: String -> String
 convertToHTML' = unlines.map (convertToHTML.escapeChars).lines
```

now to the escapeChar section. Which shoots me an error of not matching types, which comes from the naked x's down there. Do I declare x as a variable earlier in the code to call it here?

```
 escapeChar :: Char -> String
 escapeChar '&' = "&amp;"
 escapeChar '<' = "&lt;"
 escapeChar x   = x
```

and the escapeChars which calls the function

```
 escapeChars :: String -> String
 escapeChars = concatMap escapeChar
```

finally, the doubleHashes helper function...

```
 doubleHashes ('#' : '#' : []) = True
 doubleHashes _ _ = False --different amounts of arguments.
```

my main method however is working perfectly! In which I'm getting the contents from reading the input file, and finally calling to:

```
 writeFile outFile $ convertToHTML' $ contents
```

I know I'm missing some easy code, but I just can't figure it out...
Thanks

Comment: The one important thing you failed to notice in my previous answer is that some of the converters operate on lines (so should be put in between `lines` and `unlines`), some, like `_word_` on words (`words`/`unwords`), and some, like `<` or `&` on raw symbols. You should combine all three  instead of trying to do everything on lines - in your case `&` will only be converted to `&amp;` if it's the only character in the line.

Comment: I'd be glad to help you out more directly, but comments aren't a particularly good place for this. Feel free to drop into [the Haskell chatroom on SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54215/haskell) though.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. I dont have enough reputation to go into the chatroom, hopefully that keeps getting higher. haha. OK, so what im trying to understand is, because your convertHeaders, first breaks the String file into individual lines, then maps our function onto each of those lines, I should have code written in our convertHeader function where, if the head of a line beginning with 1 '#', then do "this", else, proceed to iterate through, if any line has a head of '##' then modify that line with "this". and so on throughout my other functions?

Comment: I'd suggest you answer a [tag:jquery] or [tag:css] question and get this one missing upvote. I know how dumb this suggestions sounds, but [meta upvotes mean nothing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room?lq=1) to SO higher powers, apparently.

Comment: Ill definitely start doing that! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `&` and `>` is wrong: it replaces only at the first position, while instead it should replace everywhere. And it should replace before # substitution and not after, so if you have `## foo > bar` it is processed correctly.

```
escapeChars :: String -> String
escapeChars = concatMap escapeChar

escapeChar :: Char -> String
escapeChar '&' = "&amp;"
escapeChar '>' = "&gt;"
escapeChar x = [x]
```

Just compose `escapeChars` with `convertToHtml`:

```
convertToHTML' :: String -> String
convertToHTML' = unlines.map (convertToHTML . escapeChars).lines
```

If you don't need to handle `###` then to handle `##` you can write a helper function with pattern matching:

```
doubleHashes ('#' : '#' : []) = True
doubleHashes _ = False
```

Also your `h1` generator leaves `#` in the tag.

```
convertToHTML :: String -> String
convertToHTML [] = [] --prevents calling head on empty line
convertToHTML x
        | head x == '#'         = "<h1>" ++ tail x ++ "</h1>"
        | doubleHashes x        = "<h2>" ++ drop 2 x ++ "</h2>"
        | x      == "---"       = "<hr/>"
        | otherwise             = x
```

Comment: I tried to add this helper function in, but with escapeChar x = x, it is saying I have a naked expression. How would I compose the doubleHashes function to the code as well? I appreciate your help!

Comment: I've been trying to get the escape char to work, however, just having a little trouble with some error messages. I'm missing a part of code that I can't figure out at the moment... So if I'm understanding correctly, I would compose the helper functions sdoubleHashes and escapeChar to my convertToHTML function?

Comment: `doubleHashes` you plug into guard: `| doubleHashes x = ...` and `escapeChars` (not `escapeChar`) you compose this way: `convertToHTML' = unlines.map (convertToHTML . escapeChars) .lines`. oh there's bug: it should be `escapeChar x = [x]`. I edited the answer

Comment: Okay, So calling escapeChar from escapeChars, because escapeChar is the helper method. I'm still stuck on a couple of errors. Not sure if I'm fully understanding this. I get the concepts, and what the code needs to do to work, but Im guessing I'm not doing the right code for starting convertToHTML. the error is Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[Char]' Expected: string, Actual: Char, in expression: x, for 'escapeChar':escapeChar x = x    The other issue I'm running into is Equations for 'doubleHashes' have different numbers of arguments. Ill update my code on my question so you can see Thanks

Comment: awesome man, I appreciate all the help, I did go to the x = [x] which was one of those, how did I not see that kind of thing. but I'll definitely try these. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use `span`

```
Prelude> let s1 = "# one"
Prelude> let s2 = "## two"
Prelude> let (hashes, content) = span (== '#') s1
Prelude> hashes
"#"
Prelude> content
" one"
Prelude> "<h" ++ (show $ length hashes) ++ ">" ++ content ++ "</h" ++ (show $ length hashes) ++ ">"
"<h1> one</h1>"
Prelude> let (hashes, content) = span (== '#') s2
Prelude> "<h" ++ (show $ length hashes) ++ ">" ++ content ++ "</h" ++ (show $ length hashes) ++ ">"
"<h2> two</h2>"
```

You should actually call `convertToHTML` recursively on `content`.